# ¿Se entiende el verbo "canear" como "pegar, golpear" fuera de Andalucía?

Tags: verbos, significado, españa

Según el DLE, el verbo *canear* significa:

> **[canear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=77Id9rh)**
>
> 1. intr. And. encanecer (‖ ponerse cano).
> 2. tr. rur. coloq. Mur. Calentar al sol algo.

Sin embargo, aquí en Andalucía se suele entender el verbo *canear* como "pegar, golpear". Este uso está recogido en diversas fichas del [Fichero general](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/fichero-general) de la RAE, donde se puede leer:

- CANEAR (vulg.). Pegar, golpear. 'No me tires chinas, que te *caneo*.' `Dudo mucho que me *canees*.' Canear el morro a alg. Abofetearle. 'Sí, tú provócale y verás cómo te *canea el morro*.' '¡De ésta le *caneo el morro*!' [1974 Martín J. Dicc. expr. malsonantes, [ficha (PDF)](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_C/LETRA_C_I_PDF/CANEAR/00000685.pdf)]
- CANEAR: Verb. Pegar o golpear. En su origen es dar un can [[¿acepción 6?](http://dle.rae.es/?id=71dxXgr)] con la peonza. [1988 Gordaliza Aparicio, [ficha (PDF)](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_C/LETRA_C_I_PDF/CANEAR/00000687.pdf)]

Yo pensaba que *canear* como *pegar* sería una expresión exagerada, tipo "te voy a dar una [tunda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=auiYris) que te van a salir canas" y que, por tanto, se entendería solo en Andalucía al igual que la definición de "encanecer". Sin embargo, al parecer tiene un origen completamente diferente, y dado que la acepción de *can* como "golpe a una peonza" solo existe en algunas regiones del norte de España, es posible entonces que esta expresión se entienda en otras zonas del país.

¿Se entiende, por tanto, el verbo *canear* como "pegar, golpear" en otras partes de España fuera de Andalucía?

Comment: No. Nunca lo había oído... no se usa por aquí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo soy oriundo de Madrid y entendía "canear" con ese significado. Nunca lo asocié a "dejar a alguien con el pelo blanco", pese a las otras acepciones de "canear".

Muchos diccionarios como [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/canear) o [diccionariolibre](http://diccionariolibre.com/definicion/canear) recogen esta acepción (su uso se entiende fuera de Andalucía, y posiblemente se entienda en [América también](http://www.jergasdehablahispana.org/?pais=Per%FA&palabra=canear&tipobusqueda=1))

Yo siempre lo relacioné más con "meter caña". Resulta que hay un par de homófomos de "cana" (ver las dos últimas entradas de [este enlace a Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?cana)).

*Canna* en latín es una vara (Lo vemos más claro en la [etimología de *caña*](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?can.a)), con lo cual para mí *canear* siempre significó "Pegar con una vara".

Answer (score 0):

En el sur cuando alguien te gana facilmente al padle decimos hubo "caneo gordo". Es decir, fuiste vencido de una manera "humillante", algo mas relacionado con lo de "meter caña"

Answer (score 0):

Yo también siempre entendí que era pegar con una vara, que venía de ‘caña’. Soy de Badajoz y se usa muy extendido, pero hoy he descubierto que mi pareja, de Valencia con orígenes madrileños, no conocía la expresión.